# Process a list by chunks generated using Spliterator instance type error

Tags: java, stream, java-stream, spliterator

In this program, there is a type error which I can't seem to be able to fix. The program was generated by ChatGPT and all other implementations he generated were correct. What did it miss ?

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {

// Create a stream of integers from 1 to 10
IntStream stream = IntStream.range(1, 11);

// Process the stream in chunks of size 3 using a spliterator
int chunkSize = 3;
List<List<Integer>> chunks =
    StreamSupport.stream(
            new Spliterator<Integer>() {
              private final Spliterator<Integer> spliterator = stream.spliterator();
              private final List<Integer> chunk = new ArrayList<>(chunkSize);

              @Override
              public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super Integer> action) {
                if (chunk.size() == chunkSize) {
                  action.accept(new ArrayList<>(chunk));    // TypeError
                  chunk.clear();
                  return true;
                }
                if (spliterator.tryAdvance(
                    elem -> {
                      chunk.add(elem);
                      if (chunk.size() == chunkSize) {
                        action.accept(new ArrayList<>(chunk));  // TypeError
                        chunk.clear();
                      }
                    })) {
                  if (!chunk.isEmpty()) {
                    action.accept(new ArrayList<>(chunk));    // TypeError
                    chunk.clear();
                  }
                  return true;
                }
                return false;
              }

              @Override
              public Spliterator<Integer> trySplit() {
                return null;
              }

              @Override
              public long estimateSize() {
                return spliterator.estimateSize();
              }

              @Override
              public int characteristics() {
                return spliterator.characteristics();
              }
            },
            false)
        .toList();

// Print the chunks
for (List<Integer> chunk : chunks) {
  System.out.println(chunk);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Consumer<? super Integer> action` expects to accept objects of type `Integer` but you are supplying objects of type `List<Integer>`.

This can't possible compile:

```
Consumer<? super Integer> action = // ...
action.accept(new ArrayList<Integer>());
```

This could:

```
Consumer<? super ArrayList<Integer>> action = // ...
action.accept(new ArrayList<Integer>());
```

Comment: Thank you !! I managed to figure it all out